# Attach informations to `dataTransfer` with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, drag, data-transfer

On dragstart I'm trying to attach a text to the dragged image. So that I can identify it later in the `drop` method:

```
 var drag = function(event){
    event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('text', 'ww');
```

But somehow, even directly after attaching the text, I cannot access it anymore: It is `undefinded`

```
 event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('text')
```

**How can I attach informations to the `dataTransfer`-object and access them later in the `drop`-event?** Thanks

You can experiment with this code:

```js
var allowDrop = function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
};

var drop = function(ev) {
  var attached_text = ev.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData("text"); 
  
  //HERE I TRY TO GET THE ATTACHED TEXT
  //ITS EMPTY
  $('#attach_1').text(attached_text);
};
  

var drag = function(event){
  event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('text', 'ww');
  
  var attached_text  = (event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('text'));
  
  //RIGHT AFTER I ATTACHED THE TEXT ITS NOT ACCESIBLE
  $('#attach_2').text(attached_text);
}


$('*[data-dragname="tree_icon_drag"]').on('drag', drag);

$('#drop').on('drop',  drop);
$('#drop').on('dragover', allowDrop);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="attach_1"></p>
<p id="attach_2"></p>
         
           
           <img src="http://agarwal.seas.upenn.edu/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/person_default_208x208-1.png" data-dragname="tree_icon_drag"/>
         

<div id="drop" style="background-color:red; width:300px; height:300px">
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the data in the `dragstart` event not the `drag` event

```
var dragstart = function(event){
  event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('text', 'ww');
  var attached_text  = (event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('text'));
  $('#attach_2').text(attached_text);  
};
$('*[data-dragname="tree_icon_drag"]').on('dragstart', dragstart);
```

Demo

```js
var allowDrop = function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
};

var drop = function(ev) {
  var attached_text = ev.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData("text"); 
  $('#attach_1').text(attached_text);
};

var drag = function(event){};
var dragstart = function(event){
  event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('text', 'ww');
  var attached_text  = (event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('text'));
  $('#attach_2').text(attached_text);  
};
$('*[data-dragname="tree_icon_drag"]')
    .on('drag', drag)
    .on('dragstart', dragstart);

$('#drop').on('drop',  drop)
          .on('dragover', allowDrop);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="attach_1"></p>
<p id="attach_2"></p>
<img src="http://agarwal.seas.upenn.edu/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/person_default_208x208-1.png" data-dragname="tree_icon_drag"/>
<div id="drop" style="background-color:red; width:300px; height:300px"></div>
```